# How to exclude Chrome from Fiddler Classic?

Tags: fiddler

I have Fiddler set to decrypt traffic from non-browsers, but it's still blocking my internet for Chrome. In the past, this setting allowed Chrome to have internet, but something changed and it no longer works.